# can you use firebase dynamic link without App Store Id

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store, firebase-dynamic-links

Im testing a firebase dynamic link with my test flutter iOS and android app. I was wondering do you have to upload the app to App Store and google play store to use dynamic link or is there a method to use the future to launch the app for test proposes. What I'm trying to achieve is to trigger a function within flutter using a URL. so if you have any information about this please let me know and if you have any suggestion that would be appreciated

Comment: App store ID is only used to re-direct a deep-link opening to the store when the app is not installed on the device. So yes, you can test it without having this optional part

Comment: so if I select (open the deep link URL in a browser ) I can use it to bring up my app when the url is entered ?? since I'm following a lesson and it does not provide how they select the app but id does not select the that option to preform the desired function I want to happen in the end

Comment: The easiest thing you can do is sending yourself an email with the FDL link, click it and see what happens. To automatically open your Android/iOS app there are some small app and server configurations to apply, on Android is called app-link and requires an `assetlinks.json` on host side, on iOS is called UniversalLink and you need a file called `apple-app-site-association` in the same place

Comment: one last question , in one of the firebase YouTube videos they use google photos app id . and mentioned it can be a temporary solution. is this ok ?

Comment: Yes, you can redirect your users where you want for testing purposes, to check if re-direction on stores works, you can use store id of other apps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app store ID parameter (`isi`) is optional. If you omit it when you click the link it just won't do anything (or do some fallback action based on link parameters).

In the meantime just to test if your store redirection works you can use the app store-id of any App Store app. Just don't forget to change it before publishing your app.

You can find all available Firebase Dynamic Link parameters [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually)